# Omniauth - Origin is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using the gem with twitter. On callback, check if the user exists and create him or send him back to the homepage. 
I might be doing something wrong, but in my callback code, **request.env['omniauth.origin'] is nil**.

My code is quite simple : 
**whatever.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("twitter-connect.png"), "/auth/twitter" %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    if !user.email
        redirect_to confirm_path, :notice => "Add your email!"
    else
        redirect_to request.env['omniauth.origin'] || root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
    end
end
```

If I raise **request.env['omniauth.origin']** right after callback, i get a **nil** object.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of omniauth are you using?

Comment: I ask because, I think newer versions of omniauth are having issues related to this.

Comment: HI Aditya. I just updated this morning on 0.2.4, so latest release.

Comment: I have the same issue with 0.2.3 and 0.2.4. In failure callback I don't get any omniauth.origin. I've also tried appending ?origin=/foo to my /auth/google link but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try version 0.2.0 - I've been able to get this version to work without any issues with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2-p180.

1. Shouldn't your line above read as

   user = auth.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
2. As for `omniauth.origin` being `nil`, see [this discussion](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/306).

Comment: Hi mike, thx for the direction. 
Regarding the 1), not sure => i'm trying to find a user with the info in auth, and creating him if i don't find him.

Comment: Well, my point is that you cannot do `User.find_by_provider_and_uid` as the User model does not have provider/uid fields; the last I checked the `find_by_*` dynamic finder allows you to specify attributes of that specific model only.  On the other hand you can check to see if the current auth has an associated user, i.e. `if current_user == auth.user`.  Check out the logic I used [here](https://github.com/bsodmike/omniauth_scratch/blob/50d9e9ca37dae1c69818a0454e301178ff3e0759/app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb); I took the approach of doing `if current_user && authentication`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually set the origin in the link in your view. In Rails 4, request.original_url is the best way to do this.

In your link_to Twitter button, you can set the origin manually:

```
"/auth/twitter?origin=#{request.original_url}"
```

Then in your SessionsController when you redirect to request.env['omniauth.origin'], it should function correctly.